# Convergence in distribution and convergence of expectation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\sup_n \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^{r+\epsilon}]<\infty$ and $\sup_n \mathbb{E}[|Y_n|^{r+\epsilon}]<\infty$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and $r\geq 1$. Denote by $F_n(x)$ and $G_n(x)$ the distributions of $X_n$ and $Y_n$, respectively. If we have
$$|F_n(x)-G_n(x)|\leq \mathcal{O}(n^{-1}),$$
for all $x$, and $Y_n$ converges in distribution to $Y$, then is the following statement valid?$$\Big|\mathbb{E}[X_n^r]-\mathbb{E}[Y^r]\Big|\leq \mathcal{O}(n^{-1}).$$

**Note:** I know that if $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$, and $(X_n)$ are uniformly integrable, then
$$\mathbb{E}[X_n]\to \mathbb{E}[X].$$

Comment: Are you sure you know what uniformly integrable means?

Comment: I modified my question. @Did